# Objective-C Stack implementation

Tags: objective-c, stack

I just started coding in Objective-C and would like to know if my simple implementation of a Stack is acceptable & what ways would you improve the Stack code, or the Main code? i'm curious of things such as (but not limited to):

1. formatting
2. edge cases
3. run time (like one part where try to manipulate strings in `description`)
4. general good practice
5. memory management practices (i'm using ARC in this code)

Stack.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Stack : NSObject

-(void)push:(id)obj;
-(id)pop;
-(NSUInteger)size;
-(id)peek;
-(BOOL)isEmpty;

@end
```

Stack.m file:

```
#import "Stack.h"

@implementation Stack{
    NSMutableArray *stack;
}

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self!=nil){
        stack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)push:(id)obj{
    [stack addObject:obj];
}

-(id)pop{
    id lastObj = [stack lastObject];
    [stack removeLastObject];
    return lastObj;
}

-(NSUInteger)size{
    return stack.count;
}

-(id)peek{
    return [[stack lastObject] copy];
}

-(BOOL)isEmpty{
    return stack.count == 0;
}

-(NSString *)description{
    NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"["];
    for (id s in stack) {
        [result appendFormat:@"%@, ",[s description]];
    }
    if (stack.count>0) {
        result = [[result stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@", "]] mutableCopy];
    }
    [result appendString:@"]"];
    return result;
}

@end
```

Lastly, this is how i verify my code is "working":

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "Stack.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        Stack *s1 = [[Stack alloc] init];
        assert([s1 size]==0);
        assert([s1 pop]==nil);
        assert([s1 peek]==nil);
        assert([s1 isEmpty]==YES);
        NSLog(@"first set of tests passed");
        [s1 push:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
        [s1 push:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]];
        [s1 push:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]];
        NSLog(@"%@",[s1 description]);
        assert(![s1 isEmpty]);
        assert(s1.size == 3);
        assert([[s1 peek] isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]]);
        assert([[s1 pop] isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]]);
        assert(s1.size == 2);
        assert([[s1 pop] isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]]);
        assert(![[s1 pop] isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]]);
        assert([s1 pop] == nil);
        assert(s1.isEmpty);
        NSLog(@"second set of tests passed");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(id)pop{
    id lastObj = [stack lastObject];
    [stack removeLastObject];
    return lastObj;
}
```

Not sure if you are using ARC, but without ARC this is a potential use-after-free bug.  If you are not using ARC you should consider:

```
-(id)pop{
    id lastObj = [stack lastObject];

    if (lastObj)                         // < -- now checking for nil
    {
       [[lastObj retain] autorelease];   // < -- this line added

       [stack removeLastObject];
    }
    return lastObj;
}
```

(This also assumes that the objects in the stack are `NSObject`s, but I believe `NSMutableArray` makes the same assumption...)

This bumps the ref count up so that the next line (which will cause the `NSMutableArray` to release its reference to the object) does not end up deallocating the object.

**Update on second reading:**

Also, what do you do when `lastObj` is `nil` (i.e. too many `pop`s)?  Doesn't seem like you've handled that case.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention i'm using ARC, the edit is in now. Oh, and when you do `[[lastObj retain] autorelease];` in non-ARC code, do you have to also manually release the `lastObj` later? like... in the `dealloc`? or where?

Comment: @DavidT. - `retain` increments the count, then `autorelease` will set it up to be decremented later.  (When the pool is drained, usually inside the run loop.)  When the count reaches 0 (inside `release`) then `dealloc` is called.